# Make border show for selected button of multiple row of buttons

Tags: xaml, button, uwp

I used following style for showing bottom border for button on mouse hover and click.. its working fine, but after clicking the border is not showing

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleOrders1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.Background)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.BorderBrush)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C8CA1"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.BorderThickness)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.Background)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C8CA1"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.Background)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C8CA1"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.Background)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.BorderThickness)">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup"/>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Background="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

i want to make button with bottom border after clicked and until selecting next button please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, using the [RadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RadioButton) should meet your requirement.

You could custom its style and make it looks like a button, then you could add other effect in its visual state.

I've made a simple style for you reference:

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,6,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Content="option1" GroupName="r" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
            <RadioButton Content="option2" GroupName="r" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
            <RadioButton Content="option3" GroupName="r" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```